# keeping current theme and adding actionBar to app

Tags: android, styles, themes

I'm currently using the standard `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` and would like to keep that, but to use an actionBar I have to use `Theme.Sherlock` as the parent. Is there a way around this?

If not, how can I use `Theme.Sherlock` as a parent and keep what I had before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Theme.Light.NoTitleBar then ActionBar will not be shown. ActionBar is nothing but a type of TitleBar.

If you already have some theme with some styles and want to use the actionbar then try below

For Dark theme

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock"></style>
```

For Light theme

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"></style>
```